# DQ Currents in the Induction Motor Model

Tags: motor, power-electronics, motor-controller, induction-motor, modeling

While studying the Induction Motor modelling and also its Vector control using DQ currents decoupling method.. I am finding it hard to see which current is which on the model diagrams. Can anyone point out which currents in the model circuits are Iq and Id?[image: Induction Motor Model Per Phase[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S8Cx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct currents are the real components and the quadrature currents are the reactive or imaginary components.